# No Emulator tab in Edit Configurations in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, emulation

General and Miscellaneous tabs are showing but Emulator tab is missing which was up next to General in Android Studio 1.4 before updating to Android Studio 1.5 - I cannot fix it.

[image]

Comment: Issues like these make me feel that we were better off with Eclipse+ADT.

Comment: this helped me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67034922/android-studio-4-1-emulator-sidebar

Answer (score 4):

My solution was to rename  /tools/emulator
to /tools/emulator.0

And then just have the below shell script that calls the emulator.0 and appends the qemu flags

```
#!/bin/bash

# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in

SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do # resolve $SOURCE until the file is no longer a symlink
  DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
  SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
  [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE" # if $SOURCE was a relative symlink, we need to resolve it relative to the path where the symlink file was located
done
DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"

# echo "DIR is '$DIR'"
$DIR/emulator.0 "$@" -qemu -m 512 -enable-kvm
```

Comment: where do you add this script

Comment: in   <myhome>/Android.sdk/tools/

Comment: @VP Do I need to modify the content of the /tools/emulator ?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bug, there is [issue 195031](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195031) for this case

**Updated**

I don't know how to fix it, but you can try next

1. Find `workspace.xml` in you project dir
2. Find your configuration, it should look like

   `<configuration default="false" name="app" type="AndroidRunConfigurationType" factoryName="Android Application">`

and also check `name` attribute, your configuration may named different

3. Write params you need, e. g.

   `<option name="USE_COMMAND_LINE" value="true" />
    <option name="COMMAND_LINE" value="" />
    <option name="WIPE_USER_DATA" value="false" />
    <option name="DISABLE_BOOT_ANIMATION" value="false" />
    <option name="NETWORK_SPEED" value="full" />
    <option name="NETWORK_LATENCY" value="none" />`

Maybe it will work

Comment: Ask same question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131120/where-is-emulator-settings-is-android-studio-1-5-1

Comment: Didn't work for me. Intellij overwrites the `workspace.xml` every time I change it.

Answer (score 0):

As "Emulator" tab doesn't exist in configuration any more, there is workaround I found;

Assuming that the location of `Android/Sdk` is in home directory; Run following command

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64 ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator64-x86 -avd <AVD_NAME> -qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm
```

**Note**

- Ensure that you have installed System images. You can check it in `~/Android/Sdk/system-images`
- Ensure that virtualization is on in BIOS and supported by your current OS/machine. [Steps](https://vthakkar1994.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/creating-virtual-machine-using-kvm-and-virt-installvirt-manager/)
- You have created AVD that you can find in "~/.android/avd". Mention the name in above command. You can also check the list of AVDs using `emulator -list-avds` from `\Android\tools` folder.

[Source](https://github.com/uw-it-aca/spacescout-android/issues/4)

Comment: bash: /home/chinkysight/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator64-x86: No such file or directory

Comment: Try with `Android/Sdk/tools/emulator`. I tried those things around 2-3 years back. So I didn't remember exact solution now.

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding a "<module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/android/..." line in Project directory, file .idea/modules.xml the tab appears:

```
{
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
    <component name="ProjectModuleManager">
        <modules>
            <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/renal_calc_flutter.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/renal_calc_flutter.iml" />
            <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/android/renal_calc_flutter_android.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/android/renal_calc_flutter_android.iml" />
        </modules>
     </component>
 </project>
}
```