# How to add KVM replacement of HAXM in android studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

To run Emulator android studio2.0 on ubuntu 14.04

In android studio 2.0 run->Edit configuration defaults->Android app then I am not able to see emulator option for set KVM.What is alternative to set KVM

Answer (score 0):

This is bug in android studio 2.0. They didn't provide option for emulator tab.
For more details go through this link [No Emulator tab in Edit Configurations in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909062/no-emulator-tab-in-edit-configurations-in-android-studio)