# Enable kvm as default for the emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, kvm

I was following [these directions](https://github.com/uw-it-aca/spacescout-android/wiki/1.-Setting-Up-Android-Studio-on-Ubuntu) to get the emulator working in Android Studio in Ubuntu Linux. Step 8 says:

> 8. Add the emulator command line options.
>
>    i. In Android Studio, go to Run > Edit Configurations.
>      ii. To set as global default for all projects, select "Android Application" under "Defaults".
>      iii. Go to the emulator tab, check "Additional command line options" and add:
>
>    ```
>    -qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm
>    ```

But I don't see an emulator tab. Did something change? Where do I add the additional command line options?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[This bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194713) indicates that this was removed on purpose but no alternative way to enter these settings was provided.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35822173/1396068) seems to provide a workaround.
This worked for me but beware that you'll need to specify the same amount of memory as for the AVD in the script, so this might not work for you if you have more than one AVD for testing. C.f. [the emulator command line options](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html).

Comment: Hey I am following the same source as in the question, and I am not able to perform this command: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/chinkysight/Sdk/tools/lib64 ./emulator64-x86 -avd Pixel_C_API_R_Tablet_  -qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm
bash: ./emulator64-x86: No such file or directory