# Running Android emulator with -noaudio option returns "qemu-system-i386.exe: -audio: invalid option"

Tags: android, audio, sdk, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

1. I'm running Windows 10, 64 bit, Android Studio 2.2.2. When creating an AVD from the Android SDK's AVD Manager, I don't see an option to completeley disable audio (input and output). I'm using Android SDK which has verion of Android Tools 25.2.2). In older AVD manager, i recall that option to completely disable audio on AVD was present.
2. When I want to create a batch script, to run with `-noaudio` option, as mentioned in the Google's official [Control the Emulator from the Command Line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html) page, I'm running the command as `emulator.exe -avd Nexus_4 -noaudio`, but it throws error

> `qemu-system-i386.exe: -audio: invalid option`

3. Android Emulator dialog opens, with indeterminate progress bar, and the AVD doesn't start at all. Keeps loading forever.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have tested this on Linux. (For windows checkout comments or @Tekk answer)
If you don't want audio simply use:

```
export QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none && emulator -avd Nexus_4
```

TL;DR

[Quote from here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208176)

> Based on some digging around, it looks like QEMU2 removed the ability to completely disabled audio - you can specify which sound card the audio goes through, but can't turn it off altogether. The "-audio" flag was replaced with "-soundhw", which lets us specify which sound card to use.
>
> QEMU1 (using the "-engine classic" emulator command line flag) does work when "-noaudio" is passed), but passing "-soundhw none" to QEMU2 also fails.

**Solution:**

[Post about emulated audio devices](https://www.wagner.pp.ru/fossil/vws/wiki?name=QEMU%20audio)

On linux if I want sound I use:

```
export QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=pa && emulator.orig -avd Nexus_S_api_23
```

It works fine. Also I don't have 100% CPU usage

[My snippet](https://gist.github.com/gelldur/b5e605a2a8898708fa8c27b7690526a2):

```
#!/bin/bash
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/35822173/1052261
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in

SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do # resolve $SOURCE until the file is no longer a symlink
  DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
  SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
  [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE" # if $SOURCE was a relative symlink, we need to resolve it relative to the path where the symlink file was located
done
DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"

#echo "DIR is '$DIR'"
#If you want audio pass QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=pa -> https://www.wagner.pp.ru/fossil/vws/wiki?name=QEMU+audio
export QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none && $DIR/emulator.orig -use-system-libs "$@" -qemu -m 512 -enable-kvm
```

Simply replace `Android-sdk/tools/emulator` to `Android-sdk/tools/emulator.orig`
Then create script with above source in `Android-sdk/tools/emulator` (Allow for execution).

Remember sometimes when android sdk will upgrade it will remove this script ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Instead of `export` I've had to use `set` command on Windows 10, also `&&` didn't worked, so I've only ran these two commands **`set QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none` and then `emulator -avd Nexus_4`** and can confirm that sound is now really disabled in QEMU. Also problems like 40-100% CPU drain, after few hours of emulator inactivity are gone.

Comment: Sorry, after a long time I've got back to this and sure I've accepted your answer! Many thanks, very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Dawid Drozd's answer, I've created a Windows batch script that will run AVD without sound input/output. Just give the script a parameter of AVD name.

The trick is to run `set QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none` before executing AVD.

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" goto usage
set QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none
@echo Running AVD "%1" without sound...
@echo.
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\emulator.exe -avd %1
goto :eof

:usage
@echo.
@echo -----------------------------------
@echo Usage: %0 ^<avd-name^>
@echo -----------------------------------
@echo.
@timeout 3 >0
exit /B 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it:

```
$ cd /opt/android-sdk/emulator 
$ mv emulator{,.orig}
$ cat <<EOF > emulator
heredoc> #!/bin/sh
heredoc> 
heredoc> QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none `dirname $0`/emulator.orig "$@"
heredoc> EOF
$ chmod +x emulator
```