# Disabling Audio on Android Emulator

Tags: android, audio, android-emulator, android-studio-2.2

I have been using Android Studio using software emulation as my then processor didn't support VT-x.  Having now upgraded, the emulator doesn't boot and I get high CPU usage and the following message when loading from the AVD manager:

Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
**audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed**
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554

Having seen [High CPU usage with Android emulator (qemu-system-i386.exe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063267/high-cpu-usage-with-android-emulator-qemu-system-i386-exe) I've changed the config file to hw.AudioInput=no but the problem remains.

I even uninstalled the Microsoft generic audio drivers and installed the ones for my motherboard.  No change.

Everything still works fine with a software emulator but the extra speed I've seen on another machine makes getting this to work worth it.

Android Studio Version 2.2.3
HAXM 6.0.5

Any ideas from anyone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Android emulator with -noaudio option returns "qemu-system-i386.exe: -audio: invalid option"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272884/running-android-emulator-with-noaudio-option-returns-qemu-system-i386-exe-au)