# Android Studio 4.1+ emulator sidebar?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, emulation

This question been bugging me since the release of the built-in emulator tab.
How to make it appear? Like, enforce it.

Because it just seems to appear whenever. I work mainly with Flutter projects and some projects just open and there it is. Other projects don't have the emulator tab so I have to run it in a separate window like it used to be. There are no options anywhere - it either "is" or not. I want consistency and I like it being a tab. How to enable it once and for all? Is it possible?

Comment: @Onik yes, the checkmark is there, yet no sidebar tab. It just doesn't work for me for some reason.

Comment: @Onik that's the thing - I fire up an emulator, just in a separate window, and it works like normal. This whole problem is so.. tiering. My projects are fine. Sometimes I need a few instances of the Android Studio and then one may have the tab for emulator, another project won't.. all the same. Hope they make a normal switch for this in the future, switch that works.

Comment: Do you mean firing the emulator inside a pane in Android Studio as opposed to floating?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solution is quite simple, if I don't see emulator in my Flutter project, I check in File->Project Structure, see picture.

There has to be an "Android" module, if there is none, just add it from a '+' menu, that's all, the Emulator tab will appear.

[image]

Comment: Man, take my heart ❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤

Comment: this does not work anymore with Android Studio Artic Fox 2020.3 :(

Comment: @grAPPfruit you're sure? I checked with 2020.3.1 Patch 3 and it's still there^^

Comment: Yes, I am sure - but I am talking about a Flutter setup.
It's a really strange behavior. I opened an existing project and the "Project Settings" window looks the old way. After clicking around a bit it changed to the new layout and the "Emulator"-Window as well as "Logcat" was gone and I cant get it back.
The Emulator is still running in the window which just disappeared ... and I cannot access it anymore :(

Comment: I'm also talking about Flutter, but what you mean by the "new layout" - new layout of Project Settings window? Even after creating a brand new Flutter project of fully updated IDE (Flutter as well) it doesn't look any different, can still do the "+" trick. Must be some local IDE settings issue I guess.