# Emulator tool window missing from android studio

Tags: android-studio

My Android Studio IDE is missing the tool window "Emulator" in **View** -> **Tool Windows** though the "Launch in a tool window" option is checked in **File** -> **Settings** -> **Tools** -> **Emulator**.

I don't know what changed this but it used to work properly.

I can't seem to find anyone with the same issue.

Comment: seriously nobody knows why it's gone?

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I am also facing the problem now.

Comment: Same issue. No clue why

Comment: In addition - it's visible if I open a pure android project. It is not showing for flutter projects

Comment: when I launch the emulator it still appears outside, even after going to settings to select the launch in tool setting. it still does not launch inside the android studio, used to launch in the older updates, I enjoyed it... I miss it... why does android studio updates always gotta be shitty.. too much fixing here and there

Comment: so after doing some research I found the answer follow this link it will lead you to the answers you seek.. hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67034922/android-studio-4-1-emulator-sidebar

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally, this solved the problem in my case.

Go to `File`-> `Project Structure`->`Modules` and add `Android` and `Apply`.

Automatically displays Emulator Menu in Right Panel!

Answer (score -2):

First , you should check the following things:

1- Install Java JDK .

2- add Path(JAVA_HOME) to environment variables ( Windows operating system) .

3- Install a Gradle
4-add Path(GRADLE_HOME) to the environment variables .

5- Install the SDK Android

6- add Path (ANDROID_HOME) to the environment variables (ANDROID_HOME).

Comment: you could show how to do all that and further explain your points, they are vague