# Android Studio Emulator Tool Windows Not Show

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I was creating a flutter project, but I want to run my AVD in the android studio window itself, I already select the option in "Settings-> Tools-> Emulator" and check the option that says "Launch in a tool windows" but it still executes me regardless of the emulator.
[image]

I've already done several unsuccessful searches, does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

---Updated-----
Create a project in normal java and there if that window appears I think it is a problem in flutter or something similar.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally! This is the solution [Android Studio 4.1+ emulator sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67034922/android-studio-4-1-emulator-sidebar)

Go to File->Project Structure->Modules and add Android Framework and Apply.

Automatically displays Emulator Menu in Right Panel!

Comment: this does not work anymore with Android Studio Artic Fox 2020.3 :(

Answer (score 13):

Try `File`-> `Project Structure`-> `Modules` and add `Android` and `Apply`.

Comment: this does not work anymore with Android Studio Artic Fox 2020.3 :(

Comment: creating new project using flutter create also should work

Comment: @grAPPfruit  It still works in Arctic Fox 2020.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

In [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator) doc.

- Click **File > Settings > Tools > Emulator** (or Android Studio >
  Preferences > Tools > Emulator on macOS), then select Launch in a
  tool window and click OK.

In Your case:

1. If the Emulator window didn't automatically appear, open it by
   clicking **View > Tool Windows > Emulator**.
2. Start your virtual device using the AVD Manager or by targeting it
   when running your app.

**EDIT:**

- AVD Manager > Actions Setting > **Cool Boot Now**

It directly forces start your emulator.

Comment: thanks for reply, I already did all these steps and it still does not quit, restart windows too, I have android studio 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->Project Structure->Modules. Click on the + (Plus) icon on the top middle and add Android then OK.

Tested on Android Studio 2020.3.1 patch 4. Should work the same on other releases