# Android Studio doesn't open emulator in Tool window when inside Flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I have the "Launch in a tool window" option selected in Android Studio Emulator settings. It shows the emulator in a tool window correctly for an Android project, but it does not work inside a Flutter project. The emulator option does not even appear in View->Tool Windows when I'm inside a Flutter project, unlike an Android project which is shown below:

[Android Studio's emulator in a tool window in Android project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucztQ.png)

Is there a way to enable this option for a Flutter project too?

Comment: got any solutions?

Comment: Found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251452/android-studio-emulator-tool-windows-not-show